# Is there any difference in a plain text link on a page, and a hyperlink SEO wise?

Tags: seo, html, links, hyperlink

So I am making an HTML sitemap for my users, mostly to see how it affects SEO, and to see if it would be beneficial visitor-wise.

Is there any difference between the two types of links, and how search engines see them?

Plain text:

```html
http://www.facebook.com/page
```

Hyperlink:

```html
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/page">Facebook Page</a>
```

Are these links seen differently by search engines such as Google? Which one is better for this situation?

Comment: Plain text is not a link. So yes. There is a difference.

Comment: Would the second example be better, or would it be better to do `<a href="http://www.facebook.com/page">http://www.facebook.com/page</a>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Raw Text: `http://www.example.com`

   - *Treated as a mention and Google treats [mentions as a very relatively weak SEO signal](https://www.stonetemple.com/does-google-treat-url-mentions-like-links/) and passes no [link juice](https://www.crazyegg.com/blog/glossary/link-juice/).*
2. Anchor Text Keyword: `<a href="http://www.example.com">Mojo</a>`

   - *Counts as a mention, passes juice to the receiving site and helps keyword relevancy to a certain degree, too many of the same anchor links like these can actually work as a negative as Google or Bing may consider it [unnatural links](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2604774?hl=en).*
3. Anchor Text Mention: `<a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a>`

   - *Counts as a mention and passes juice to the receiving site.*
4. Links with nofollow: `<a href="http://www.google.co.uk/" rel="nofollow">`

   - *No juice is passed. Typically in error, most webmasters will assume that links that have the rel attitude nofollow have no benefit to their site, this is simply not true. [Nofollow links have many hidden powers](https://moz.com/blog/the-hidden-power-of-nofollow-links) and can can help Google or Bing establish how relevant your content is. These also help diversify your [link profile](http://searchengineland.com/how-checking-your-link-profile-can-save-your-site-247100) which helps avoid [Google Penguin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Penguin).*

Comment: Very informative, thank you very much for your reply. Just to confirm, is an anchor text keyword or mention a better option? Thanks!